# how can I parse this javascript array using Map function?

Tags: autocomplete

I want to parse the below JavaScript array for using in Autocomplete control. 
The requirement is to display the value field in autocomplete textbox and store the key field as itemID.

```
{"Key":9886,"Value":"xxx"},{"Key":9887,"Value":"yyy"},{"Key":5634,"Value":"zzz"},{"Key":9888,"Value":"abcd"}
```

I tried the below code to map this array as source for my textbox:

````
var itemID;
  $("#txtbox").autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'controller/Getdata',
                    data:JSON.stringify({'term' :request.term}),
                    dataType: 'json',
                    contentType: 'application/json',
                    success: function(data) {                    
                      response(
                            $.map(data,
                                function(object) {
                                    return {
                                        label: object.value,
                                        value: object.key
                                    }                                 

                                })
                )
                    },
                    error: function(xhr, status, error) {                      
                        alert(error);
                    }

                });
            },
            minLength: 2,
            select: function (e, ui) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $("#txtbox").val(ui.item.value); 
                itemID = ui.item.key;
            }

        });```

Appreciate any help on this.
````

Comment: Your question is quite unclear. Please provide a code example of what you'd like to achieve.

Comment: @shafeena please use chosen.js https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/. Hope that is your requirement

Comment: @Nino, I have put sample code

Comment: @Abdulla, Thanks. But that didnt help. Need to set store itemID into a variable when user selects an item from autocomplete menu.

Answer (score 0):

The below code worked to map autocomplete source to dictionary array:

```
$("#txtbox").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'controller/Getdata',
                data: JSON.stringify({ 'term': request.term }),
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                success: function (data) {
                    var parsedData = JSON.parse(data);
                    var arr = $.map(parsedData,
                        function (item) {
                            return {
                                label:item.Value,
                                value:item.Key
                            }}
                    );

                    response(arr);
                },
                error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                    alert('here');
                    var array = [];
                    response(array);
                }

            });
        },
        minLength: 3,

        select: function (e, ui) {
         e.preventDefault();
         $("#txtbox").val(ui.item.label);
         userID = ui.item.value;
        }

    });
```

The controller code which returns dictionary was this:

```
public ActionResult Getdata(string term)
        {
            var itemList= Provider.GetAllItems();
            var filteredItems = itemList.Where(x => x.Value.Contains(term));
            JavaScriptSerializer javaScriptSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            string result = javaScriptSerializer.Serialize(filteredItems );
            return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```